# Static Routing Configuration

Tags: vpn, routing, configuration, gateway

My network looks like this:
[image: Current Network Configuration]

The PPTP Server is currently routing all inbound PPTP connections to 192.168.1.0/24, which is good as I expect Device A and Device B to normally communicate with Device X. I can also communicate to Device X from the workstation.

With this configuration, my routing table in the main gateway looks like this:
[image: Routing Table]

However, I need to be able to access device A and device B directly from my workstation. ie. ping 192.168.2.10 and ping 192.168.3.10 from my workstation.
Is anyone able to provide some guidance on how I can achieve this via static routing or otherwise?

Comment: Is there a route on RouterA and on RouterB to send traffic for 10/24 via the VPN gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via static routing you could accomplish your goal with static routing like that:
On device x: 
route 192.168.2.10 via 192.168.1.1
route 192.168.3.10 via 192.168.1.1
route 10.0.0.103 via 192.168.1.1
or you can set 192.168.1.1 as the default gateway like this:
route 0.0.0.0 via 192.168.1.1

On main gateway: 
route 192.168.2.10 via 10.0.0.101
route 192.168.3.10 via 10.0.0.102

On router A:
route 192.168.1.2 via 10.0.0.1
route 10.0.0.103 via 10.0.0.1

On router B:
route 192.168.1.2 via 10.0.0.2
route 10.0.0.103 via 10.0.0.2
On device A:
route 192.168.1.2 via 192.168.2.1
route 10.0.0.0.103 via 192.168.2.1
or you can set 192.168.2.1 as the default gateway like this:
route 0.0.0.0 via 192.168.2.1

On device B:
route 192.168.1.2 via 192.168.3.1
route 10.0.0.0.103 via 192.168.3.1
or you can set 192.168.3.1 as the default gateway like this:
route 0.0.0.0 via 192.168.3.1

Otherwise you need to install a routing daemon on your devices which perform a dynamic routing protocol such as OSPF. 
OSPF itself would be much more effective, because as your diagram pictures, there are some IPs which are allocated dynamically. 
The above given static routes wouldn't work anymore when the dynamically allocated IPs change.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will only very rarely need to connect to these devices so setting up temporary static routes is acceptable to me. I understand some of these routing rules you suggested allow a bidirectional link, which is great. However, if i just want to be able to ping device A and device B on the workstation, am I correct in assuming I only need to set up the routes on the main gateway only?

Comment: In addition to the above, also assume that device A has its default gateway set to 192.168.2.1 and device B has its default gateway set to 192.168.3.1

Comment: If you only want to ping dev [a,b] you could configure it as the following: workstation has the main gateway as default gateway, dev a has router a default gateway, dev b has router b as default gateway. Router a and b need to know how to reach the workstation and the main gateway needs to know how to reach dev a and b. Therefore you need to configure the to- and backward routes. But as I said before you really should consider installing a dynamic routing protocol such as OSPF. If you run linux machines you could use the bird internet routing daemon for that. Regards.